# Computed Column throw can't update error even after marking it as Computed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have a computed column that is already marked as computed, but it still throw me the SqlException:

```
The column "OPPORTUNITY_VALUE" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.
```

How do I get rid of this error?

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public long? OPPORTUNITY_VALUE { get; set; }
```

Comment: Throws an exception when doing what exactly?  You haven't shown us any executable code.

Comment: Well I don't need to write any code, entity framework handle everything for me.

Comment: Exceptions don't just happen spontaneously.  *What are you attempting to do when the exception occurs*?

Comment: The exception happen when I update an item I created, but I did not set the OPPORTUNITY_VALUE value or anything like that, I just modified some other field.  What happened is that I was re-using the same instance when I would get it from database, so I guess OPPORTUNITY_VALUE would be automatically filled with whatever is in database, hence it complains when I try to save it.  However, even if I set OPPORTUNITY_VALUE to null, it still throw the error.

Comment: Please, write sql code which creating this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this was a bug in the dapper.fastcrud package my company is using, sorry.